# Let $A \in \mathcal{M}_n ( \mathbb{C} ) $ be a matrix. Do all eigenvalues of $A^k$ have the form $\lambda^k$ where $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of A?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

One contention is easy to prove: If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ then there exists nonzero $v \in \mathbb{C^n}$ such that $Av = \lambda v$, thus $A^k v  = \lambda^k v$. But, I am having trouble proving that all eigenvalues of $A^k$ are necessarily of that form. If $A$ is diagonalizable, then the result is easy to prove, but I lack of tools for manipulating the case in which $A$ is non-diagonalizable.

Comment: Any order $n$ matrix has and only has $n$ eigenvalues.

Comment: Not every matrix is diagonalizable, but every matrix over $\mathbb{C}$ is similar to a triangular matrix. (for example, to its Jordan form). The elements on the diagonal are exactly the eigenvalues of $A$, say $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n$. Thus $A^k$ is similar to a triangular matrix where the entries on the diagonal are $\lambda_1^k,...,\lambda_n^k$. Finally, similar matrices have the same eigenvalues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes. One proof is as follows.

Suppose that $\mu$ is an eigenvalue of $A^k$. Let $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_k$ denote the solutions to the equation $\lambda^k = \mu$. Because $\mu$ is an eigenvalue of $A^k$, $A^k - \mu I$ must be singular. However, we can write
$$
(A^k - \mu I) = (A - \lambda_1 I) \cdots (A - \lambda_k I).
$$
A product of matrices can only be singular if one of the matrices in the product is singular. Thus, there a $j$ for $1 \leq j \leq k$ for which $(A - \lambda_j I)$ is singular, which is to say that $\lambda_j$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.

Thus, $A$ has an eigenvalue $\lambda = \lambda_j$ for which $\lambda^k = \mu$.